# R ggrides package drawing mean line (NOT MEDIAN)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggridges

I'd like to draw a line through my rideplots for the mean. The built-in quantile arguments draw a line in the style I want, but at the *median*. How can I draw one at the mean, preferably without using [geom_vline()](https://community.rstudio.com/t/density-ridges-plotting-geom-vline-using-specific-values-for-each-distribution/38819) or [pluck at the ggplot build object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527229/draw-line-on-geom-density-ridges) but staying in the ggridges ecology?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

#adding a column for the mean of each Species of the iris dataframe
iris_meaned <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(mean_petal_len = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup()


iris_meaned %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density_ridges(
    aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species), 
    quantile_lines = T, quantiles = 2 #adding lines for the median
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = mean_petal_len, y = Species, label = round(mean_petal_len, 2)),
    size = 2, nudge_x = 0.03, nudge_y = 0.35
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(), 
    legend.position = "None"
  )
```

[image: Example with median lines]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can provide an arbitrary function to the argument `quantile_fun`. The function has to take a numeric vector as the first argument, and the number of quantiles as the second. But it's fine to ignore the second argument. The `mean()` function satisfies these criteria, and thus `quantile_fun = mean` creates vertical lines at the mean.

Note that in your example, you're plotting the text labels over and over. I've fixed the code so it works appropriately.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

iris_meaned <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(mean_petal_len = mean(Petal.Length))

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species), 
    quantile_lines = T, quantile_fun = mean)  + 
  geom_text(
    data = iris_meaned,
    aes(x = mean_petal_len, y = Species, label = round(mean_petal_len, 2)),
    size = 2, nudge_x = 0.03, nudge_y = 0.35
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
     axis.title = element_blank(), 
     legend.position = "None"
  ) 
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.155
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To provide a second example, let's draw lines at the mean as well as the mean +/- 1 standard deviation. We can do so by defining a function `meansd()` that returns a vector of these three values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

meansd <- function(x, ...) {
  mean <- mean(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  c(mean - sd, mean, mean + sd)
}

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_density_ridges(
    aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species), 
    quantile_lines = T, quantile_fun = meansd)  + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(), 
    legend.position = "None"
  ) 
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.155
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: is it possible to do this in any ways for weighted means with wtd.mean or a similar function? I keep getting errors when I try.

Comment: For succinctness, I rather avoid computing `iris_meaned` and use `stat_summary()` instead. To this end, first map the aesthetics to `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Species, fill = Species))`, then add `geom_density_ridges(quantile_lines = T, quantile_fun = mean)`, and finally `stat_summary(aes(label = round(..x.., 2)), fun = "mean", geom = "text", size = 2` . @clauswilke, is there a reason to favor `iris_meaned` nevertheless?

Comment: @Emman Is there some reference to the use of `..x..`? I cannot find it at any place. How should it be used? I ask you because trying the equivalent in my code to `label = round(Petal.Length, 2)` (inside `stat_summary` as you do) does not work. (and it works using `..x..` exactly as you) Thanks!

Comment: @iago, `..x..` refers to what's mapped earlier in `aes(x = blah)`. Look up "internal/special variables in ggplot". E.g.,: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140431/6105259), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067032/6105259), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570974/6105259). I don't know a formal reference though.